# Regarding google chrome extension development (tabs.onUpdated.addListener())

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, syntax-error

I am developing a google chrome extension.I want the extension to record whenever a webiste is loaded or the URL in the tab changed.
I have written the following javascript code to show a dialog box whenever a tab is updated but for some reason It gives Uncaught Syntaxerror:Unexpected Identifier.

Here is the code

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(integer tabId, object changeInfo, Tab tab)     
{
        //if(tab.url!="")
            alert(tab.url);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help.I am really not able to find a solution.

Comment: Can you paste the full error? It probably is reporting an unexpected identifier along with the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is not strictly typed, so try remove the `integer`, `object` and `Tab`:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab)     
{
    //if(tab.url!="")
        alert(tab.url);
});
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: No problem, I've been there too, doing the same misstake :) The documentation really looks copy/paste friendly.

Comment: @Ragnar tabId and changeInfo are passed but not used, why are they there? Thanks!